# count line progressivley of each file in specified folder

Tags: string, batch-file, find

I have been able to construct the following however im more after a batch that can add the results up of each file as it goes along dose anybody know how to achieve this?

```
find /C "HELLO" c:\TOM\*.TXT
```

Comment: What do you mean `the results`?

Comment: in english the result means the total sum  example 1+1= 2 two is a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirement and you want to count how many times (lines count) word "HELLO" appears across all files, then `type c:\TOM\*.TXT 2>nul |find /c "HELLO"` (`2>nul` suppresses listing of file names, if you want to see them just remove that part) should do the job.